# when tokenize arabic text with python I get strange result?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, nlp, arabic

I'v been working with NLTK for a research to tokenize Arabic text and analyze it. The problem is when I do this code:

```
bsm = 'بسم الله الرحمن الريحم'
wordsBsm = nltk.tokenize.wordpunct_tokenize(anas)
print " ".join(wordsBsm)
```

I get this our put:

```
� � س� � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � �
```

I don't know how to solve this problem!

Comment: What Python version are you using, and what encoding?

Comment: You'll want to pass a Unicode string (`bsm = u'...'`). And if you are using Windows there will be many obstacles to doing anything with Unicode on the console/interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Python 2.x, then as bobince said, this should work:

```
bsm = u'بسم الله الرحمن الريحم'
```

If you're using Python 3.x, then it should work without having to put the 'u' there. Take a look at [Python 2's Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, if you are reading the Arabic text from a file, you could do something like this:

```
unicode( open('arabic.txt', 'w').read(), 'utf-8')
```

or, depending on your file's encoding:

```
unicode( open('arabic.txt', 'w').read(), 'Windows-1256')
```